# Can 1 convolution be split into 2 convolutions?

Tags: math, signal-processing

So I'm looking to perform a 2D convolution on an RGB image. My RGB image is of shape `(2592,3888,3)` and my filter is of shape `(20,20)`

What I want to do is this:

- Split the image into two halves of equal size `(1296,3888,3)`
- Perform a convolution on each half
- Combine the convolution results to get the full convolved image

Is this possible?

I have two GPUs. I basically want to do half of the convolution on 1 GPU and the other half on the other GPU, hence the motivation for this quesiton.

When I break up the image in half and convolve each half, the combined dimensions returned are `(2554,3869,3)`, but if I convolve the entire image at once, the (correct) dimensions returned are `(2573,3869,3)`.

Is there a formula for what I want to do?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93add_method

Answer (score 2):

You can perform the convolution in two stages, but there must be an overlapping area of 19 (or possibly 20) lines on the image center to be included by both GPUs.
Better yet, if the convolution routine allows output of (size+2k-1), then the middle section can be calculated by summing these two results (properly aligned).

Answer (score 1):

It seems your result only contains the points where the convolution product is full, not applying any zero padding or similar extensions. Thus if you split exactly, the middle of the complete result is missing.

You can correct for that by introducing an overlap in the middle of the split of the filter size, that is, the left image has the columns 1 to 1306 and the second the columns 1287 to 2592 (or shifted by -1 if counting starts with 0).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can split your convolution in half.  It should be fairly straightforward for conventional GPU API's, assuming your convolution filter works in a straightforward way.

The problem you want to think carefully about is the edge effects:  what will your GPU do at the boundaries of your image?  You typically have a number of options, configurable per boundary of the texture sampling object that reads your original image: mirroring, wraparound, or a fixed color such as zero.

However, if both sides are sampling from the same original image, the boundary between the two halves will be near the center of the texture, where the edge effects don't apply!  Each half-image will apply the convolution at its own sampling locations, independent of the other.

Note that, if you are splitting the *input* image between GPU's (e.g. to minimize bandwidth between GPU and CPU), you must extend each half of the source texture by the extent of the filter -- just enough to avoid the edge effect mentioned above!